# Problema ao gerar relatório entre datas

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jasper-reports, ireport

Tenho um campo `DATETIME` com uma data e hora: `2015-08-06 08:50:28`. Estou tentando gerar um relatório passando dois parâmetros, `Data_Inicial` e `Data_Final` para que eu possa pegar todas as datas do banco que estão nesse período.

A condição ficou dessa maneira no `IReport`:

```
WHERE
     tbl_suspensao.`status` = 'Finalizado'
 AND tbl_suspensao.`data_inicio` BETWEEN  $P{Data_Inicio} AND $P{Data_Fim}
```

Esses dois parâmetros são do tipo: `Date/Time` do `java.sql.Time`. Porém quando entro com os parâmetros e dou um preview aparece a mensagem "O documento não tem páginas". Alguém pode ajudar?

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faça um teste de `data_inicio 01/01/2015` e `data_fim 12/12/2015`

Comment: Da a mesma mensagem falando que o documento não contem páginas

Comment: Então seu problema não está nas datas não pequeno gafanhoto, tem certeza que essa condição está valida `tbl_suspensao.status = 'Finalizado'` ?

Comment: Tenho sim, quando deixo só ela funciona perfeitamente. Fiz um teste e coloquei o tipo do parâmetro como apenas `DATE` e funcionou, porém não consigo estabelecer as horas.

Comment: Já troquei e funcionou rsrs, mas não da pra usar a com o horário. Mas vou deixar dessa forma mesmo. Reaproveitando a pergunta, como eu poderia fazer uma contagem no próprio relatório de quantos Clientes tem status = 'Finalizado' e quantos tem status = 'Pendente' ?

Comment: Você tem que dar um count no `status` agrupando pelo `status`

Comment: Mas te aconselho a criar outra pergunta pra não poluir essa

Comment: Eu tentei dar um count no status mas ele conta todos independente se é Finalizado ou Pendente. A expressão ficou dessa forma no campo status que adicionei na banda sumary:
`$V{tbl_suspensao_status_2}`

Comment: Entendi. Vou tentar fazer caso não eu não funcione eu abro outra pergunta.

Comment: Pode responder essa pergunta já que você me ajudou também a chegar a solução. Ou prefere que eu responda?

Comment: Pode você mesmo :}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para o problema foi alterar o tipo dos dois parâmetros para `java.util.Date` antes eles estavam como `java.sql.Time`